# ClearsSript V8ScriptEngine TypeError: form.Show is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, clearscript

I use [MS ClearScript library](https://github.com/Microsoft/ClearScript) for some dynamic parts in my system. I have some list of objects that already created in .NET(C#) code, this objects use as description for functions use. Like this (Javascript):

```
var form = MetaData.GetClass('MyFormClassName', 'FormId'); form.Show();
```

In this example a get a class `MyFormClassName` with ID `FormId` with the static method `MetaData.GetClass`. The method returns an instance of `MyFormClassName` with ID `FormId` created in.NET(C#) code. There is a method `Show()` that show windows form with parameters in an instance.

But when I call a `Show()` method I get an error:

> form.Show is not a function

The engine contains an object `Properties`, but there are no methods. Engine don't know object `Type`. When I use `AddHostObject` with name `form` it works fine, but I do not know what variable name will be used in future.

Does any body know how I can use .NET (C#) objects methods in V8ScriptEngine? Is it possible don't register host object every time for object methods use?

Comment: What is the static (declared) type of the `MetaData.GetClass` return value?
 Can you provide the full signature of that method?

Comment: public static MdElement GetClass(string mdClass, string mdClassName). Method return a inherited class of MdElement. The object as I understand is an object type returned, I try use a ToString method and it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the `MetaData.GetClass` return value type is a base class or interface that doesn't have a `Show` method.

If that's correct, then `Show` is provided by the actual type of the returned object, and [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) is required to call it.

There are several ways to deal with this:

1. Use [`HostFunctions.cast`](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/M_Microsoft_ClearScript_HostFunctions_cast__1.htm) or [`HostFunctions.asType`](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/M_Microsoft_ClearScript_HostFunctions_asType__1.htm) to downcast in JavaScript.
2. Add the attribute [`ScriptMember(ScriptMemberFlags.ExposeRuntimeType)`](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/T_Microsoft_ClearScript_ScriptMemberAttribute.htm) to your `MetaData.GetClass` implementation.
3. Set [`ScriptEngine.DisableTypeRestriction`](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/P_Microsoft_ClearScript_ScriptEngine_DisableTypeRestriction.htm) to `true` (not recommended).